# Has anyone figured out how to make Leaflet Sidebar v1 wider?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am pouring through the CSS and SCSS and I can't seem to make the sidebar wider. I'm displaying tables on it of selected features on a map. I would like it to be at least twice as wide as it is now.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Tried:

```
<style>       
body { margin:10; padding:0; }
#map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:325;} 
#properties{position: absolute; border: 2px solid black; top: 300}
#sidebar{width: 900px !important;}    
</style>

var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
                position: 'right',
                });
            map.addControl(sidebar);
```

Comment: May help to post a https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `L.Control.Sidebar.css` (so you should make the lib local) multiple times, cause sidebar's size depends on the window size. *I will show you an option of making the sidebar twice larger, you could change values to your purpose. I am adding the whole .css file with comments where there are changes*.

```
.leaflet-sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 2000; }
  .leaflet-sidebar.left {
    left: -1000px; /*has to be larger than any @media widths*/
    transition: left 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    padding-right: 0; }
    .leaflet-sidebar.left.visible {
      left: 0; }
  .leaflet-sidebar.right {
    right: -1000px; /*has to be larger than any @media widths*/
    transition: right 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    padding-left: 0; }
    .leaflet-sidebar.right.visible {
      right: 0; }
  .leaflet-sidebar > .leaflet-control {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px 24px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background: white; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px; }
    .leaflet-touch .leaflet-sidebar > .leaflet-control {
      box-shadow: none;
      border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      background-clip: padding-box; }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .leaflet-sidebar {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0; }
      .leaflet-sidebar.left.visible ~ .leaflet-left {
        left: 100%; }
      .leaflet-sidebar.right.visible ~ .leaflet-right {
        right: 100%; }
      .leaflet-sidebar.left {
        left: -100%; }
        .leaflet-sidebar.left.visible {
          left: 0; }
      .leaflet-sidebar.right {
        right: -100%; }
        .leaflet-sidebar.right.visible {
          right: 0; }
      .leaflet-sidebar > .leaflet-control {
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        border-radius: 0; }
        .leaflet-touch .leaflet-sidebar > .leaflet-control {
          border: 0; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .leaflet-sidebar {
      width: 600px; } /*make bigger here*/
      .leaflet-sidebar.left.visible ~ .leaflet-left {
        left: 600px; } /*make bigger here (move original map control)*/
      .leaflet-sidebar.right.visible ~ .leaflet-right {
        right: 600px; } } /*make bigger here*/
  @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .leaflet-sidebar {
      width: 800px; } /*make bigger here*/
      .leaflet-sidebar.left.visible ~ .leaflet-left {
        left: 800px; } /*make bigger here (move original map control)*/
      .leaflet-sidebar.right.visible ~ .leaflet-right {
        right: 800px; } } /*make bigger here*/
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .leaflet-sidebar {
      width: 920px; } /*make bigger here*/
      .leaflet-sidebar.left.visible ~ .leaflet-left {
        left: 920px; } /*make bigger here (move original map control)*/
      .leaflet-sidebar.right.visible ~ .leaflet-right {
        right: 920px; } } /*make bigger here*/
  .leaflet-sidebar .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8; }

.leaflet-left {
  transition: left 0.5s; }

.leaflet-right {
  transition: right 0.5s; }
```

Here is my result: [image]

Comment: glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by selecting the sidebar's id (*sidebar*) and then assigning a width to it.

For example, if you want the sidebar to be 900 pixels wide, you would write:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 900px;
}
```

You might have to mark it as *!important* if it does not work right away:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 900px !important;
}
```

Comment: Do you do that with CSS in your index.html file? I tried that and it did not work. :-(

Comment: You should be able to add a *<style>* tag in your HTML file. You should show some code, because it is hard to tell without seeing any code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated the post.

Comment: Just curious if you could explain the `!important` bit?

Comment: Maybe try this, right after you add the sidebar: document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "900px";